# Calling QGIS 3D view using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, 3d-map

I am working on creating a change detection script for QGIS3, that detects the differences between two DEMs and highlights the changes. Everything is working well but I have been unable to get the 3D view to work using pyqgis, I have it working using the GUI.

I want to display my output rasters in 3D view using **PyQGIS**, like this:

[image]

I have looked into the [3D Library](https://qgis.org/api/group__d.html) and the [Python API](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/Qgs3DRendererRegistry.html?highlight=3d#qgis.core.Qgs3DRendererRegistry) but I have not been able to get any of this to work.

I tried using the [Qgs3DmapScene](https://qgis.org/api/classQgs3DMapScene.html) Class but the QGIS python console does not recognize it.

How can I use the 3D View to display layers using PyQGIS? is there any example or sample of this somewhere?

*I am using QGIS 3.4.4 on Windows with Qt 5.11.2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 3.28, this is not possible. The 3D code needs restructuring so that it can be used like other parts of the QGIS libraries.

See https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2022-November/065258.html and https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2022-November/065261.html for some context.