# Communicate with QGIS 3D view via PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, 3d

I want to automate setting parameters for the QGIS 3D map view window in my project, presumably using PyQGIS.

For the standard 2D map canvas, I can access `iface.mapCanvas` and use its various methods, but I can't find an analogous `iface.mapCanvas3D` or similar. My goal is to then use methods from https://qgis.github.io/pyqgis/3.16/3d/index.html to work with it, especially `Qgs3DMapSettings` and `Qgs3DCameraPose`, once I can get my hands on the right instance. How can I access it, or do something equivalent?

(I know from [Call the QGIS 3D view using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313346/call-the-qgis-3d-view-using-pyqgis) that I can't start the 3D view from PyQGIS, but I'd be fine just reading and modifying its settings once it's active.)